# SQL Row Concatenation on joined table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've read through similar posts but cannot get my query to work.

Here's what I have:

```
SELECT u.Id,
U.FirstName as [Name],
ut.UserType,
COUNT(DISTINCT(s.rawScoreDate)) as [Total Sessions],
COUNT(DISTINCT(s.SkillId)) AS [Skills Used], 
SUM(CASE WHEN s.score in (1, 2, 3) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [Total Scores],
SUM(CASE s.score WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [1's Scored],
SUM(CASE s.score WHEN 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [2's Scored],
SUM(CASE s.score WHEN 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [3's Scored],
CAST(100.0/NULLIF(SUM(CASE WHEN s.score in (1, 2, 3) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),0) * SUM(CASE s.score WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS NUMERIC(18,2)) AS [1's %],
CAST(100.0/NULLIF(SUM(CASE WHEN s.score in (1, 2, 3) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),0) * SUM(CASE s.score WHEN 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS NUMERIC(18,2)) AS [2's %],
CAST(100.0/NULLIF(SUM(CASE WHEN s.score in (1, 2, 3) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),0) * SUM(CASE s.score WHEN 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS NUMERIC(18,2)) AS [3's %],
(SELECT SkilsName as skls FROM tblSkils as sk where sk.SkilsId=s.SkillId) as [Skills]
FROM tblUser AS u
LEFT OUTER JOIN tblRawScore AS s ON (U.Id=s.AssignedBy) JOIN tblUserType AS ut ON (u.UserTypeId=ut.Id)
WHERE u.usertypeid=4
GROUP BY u.id, u.FirstName,ut.UserType,s.SkillId
ORDER BY [Total Sessions] DESC
```

This works fine while the [Skills Used] is only 1, but if there are more than 1 I assume it will either return the 1st skill or duplicate rows in the results.

Is there a way I can put the results from the [Skills] query into a string, something like:

Skill1, Skill2, Skill3

Sorry if this is a duplicate question, but I am quite new to complex SQL queries.

Comment: There is a way to combine the skills like that.  However because of the way you are joining in tblRawScore you will only get one skill per row (and thus you will get multiple rows).  You can move the join into the subquery, but then you can't reference tblRawScore for other things you want to select in the outer query.  You could put it in both places, but then you get one row per skill that shows the scores for that skill but then combines all the skills under Skills Used.  That being said, what do you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Code:

```
STUFF((SELECT ', ' + [Skills Used]
FROM FROM tblUser AS x LEFT OUTER JOIN tblRawScore AS y ON (x.Id=y.AssignedBy)
JOIN tblUserType AS z ON (x.UserTypeId=z.Id) WHERE x.ID=u.ID FOR XML PATH('')),1,2,'')
```

Use this as one of the fields in your query.

Comment: Thanks, Not quite right for my purpose, but [put me on the right path. Thank you very much.

Comment: I added the where clause to my answer.  Try it again.  It should work better now.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to jbarker I have managed to get it working with this:

```
SELECT u.Id,
U.FirstName as [Name],
ut.UserType,
COUNT(DISTINCT(s.rawScoreDate)) as [Total Sessions],
COUNT(DISTINCT(s.SkillId)) AS [Skills Used], 
SUM(CASE WHEN s.score in (1, 2, 3) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [Total Scores],
SUM(CASE s.score WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [1's Scored],
SUM(CASE s.score WHEN 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [2's Scored],
SUM(CASE s.score WHEN 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [3's Scored],
CAST(100.0/NULLIF(SUM(CASE WHEN s.score in (1, 2, 3) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),0) * SUM(CASE s.score WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS NUMERIC(18,2)) AS [1's %],
CAST(100.0/NULLIF(SUM(CASE WHEN s.score in (1, 2, 3) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),0) * SUM(CASE s.score WHEN 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS NUMERIC(18,2)) AS [2's %],
CAST(100.0/NULLIF(SUM(CASE WHEN s.score in (1, 2, 3) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),0) * SUM(CASE s.score WHEN 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS NUMERIC(18,2)) AS [3's %],
STUFF(( SELECT ', ' + sk.SkilsName
        FROM tblskils AS sk
        WHERE sk.SkilsId=s.SkillId
        FOR XML PATH('')),1,2,'') AS [Skills Used]
```